# SQL How to show information from others tables in select requet

Tags: mysql, select, table

There are my database

```
user
id | user_code | user_name
1  | 1x2d       | Peter

shops
id | shop_code | shops_name
1  | 1234      | shop1
2  | 3456      | shop2

articles
id | art_code | art_name
1  | 5678     | computer
2  | 0987     | display

action
id | M_art_code | M_shop_code | M_user_code
1 | 5678        | 1234        | 1x2d
2 | 0987        |             | 1x2d
```

I would like to SELECT all value of action where .... with all information from other table

```
Result
M_art_code | M_shop_code | shops.shops_name | M_user_code| user.user_name
5678       | 1234        | shop1            | 1x2d       | Peter
0987       |             |                  | 1x2d       | Peter
```

I try with

```
SELECT * FROM user U, shops S, articles A, action AC 
WHERE AC.M_user_code = U.user_code
AND AC.M_shop_code = S.shops_code AND M_art_code LIKE %%
```

But with this `SELECT` I've just row ths all value not empty. I need all value.
How I can do to have I would like?

PS: sorry for my English...I'm french

Answer (score 2):

Instead of the (implicit) inner joins you have to use left joins if you want all rows from the left table regardless of the existence of a matching row from the right table.

```
SELECT ac.m_art_code,
       ac.m_shop_code,
       sh.shops_name,
       ac.m_user_code,
       us.user_name
       FROM action ac
            LEFT JOIN shops sh
                      ON sh.shop_code = ac.m_shop_code
            LEFT JOIN user us
                      ON us.user_code = ac.m_user_code;
```

Comment: `USING ()` is nicer there.

Comment: @EvanCarroll `USING()` needs the field names to be absolutely equal...

Comment: Thx sticky bit :)